# Change Font color of tr with jQuery after click on image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search for a way to change the font color of a tr with jQuery. There is an icon in the last cell of every tr. I want if I click it that the font color of the tr is changed. I used this:

```
$('#documentsTable tr').live('click', function(){
```

but it is for clicking on the whole row. What is the best way to manage this?

Best regards

Comment: if it is an image then $('#documentsTable tr img')....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the class of your icon is `icon`:

```
$('#documentsTable .icon').live('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").css("color","yourColor");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) pseudo-selector to match the last child of each element in the matched set (in this case, the last `td` in each `tr` within `#documentsTable`):

```
$('#documentsTable tr td:last-child').live('click', function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").css({color: "#ff0000"});
});
```

To attach the click event handler to an image within that `td`, simply add `img` to the end of your selector:

```
#documentsTable tr td:last-child img
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/E5hgp/9/).